# how to pass alert dialog with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I have a login page.When the user logs in correctly,I want to show an alert dialog saying that your login details have been verified.Click continue to proceed.Now I want this alert dialog to be shown on the next activity page after login.Please help me out here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmmm... sorry but it is lunch time in germany...

Comment: I think what actually you are trying to achieve  is... on Login you want to show message in alert dialogue and after clicking on that dialogue you want the user to continue with your app ???

M I right

Comment: yes sir u are right..

Answer (score 2):

change Activity to your current class and implement it sure work ......

declare this

```
SharedPreferences my_preferences;
```

in on create method

```
 this.my_preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

////////after login is done

```
if (SaveOn_preferences.getBoolean("Login", true)) {


SharedPreferences.Editor editor = my_preferences.edit();

 editor.putBoolean("Login", false);
 editor.commit();


 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(Activity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Attention!");
    builder.setMessage("your login details have been verified");
    builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
//continue activity here....

        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

    //cancel activity here      

        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
```

}

Comment: With this alert dialog,I have just one problem.Each time I switch from some other activity to this one,I get the same alert dialog again.I want to use it as a one time alert dialog i.e. only when the user logs in correctly the alert dialog displays otherwise not.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass alert dialog from one activity to another. It's wrong.
You just pass the information whatever you want to pass, using Intent's Extras.
Now, in the second activity, you just have to create alert dialog and pass the information into it.
That's it buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT pass `Dialog` - that's wrong. Pass information so next activity knows that it shall show that dialog. Put what you want into your `Intent`'s extras and next activity shall check if these data is there and act as you want.

Comment: But in the next activity how can I use Intent in alert dialog to stay on the same page.

Comment: what "the same page" if you are using two activities?